# How do I figure out where my project brings in a module I don't want to use?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, delphi-5, quickreports

I am converting a project from Delphi 5 to Delphi 2007 and am getting the compile error

> Required package 'qrpt' not found.

I am not using Quick Reports in this project and I have tried commenting out some of the units in the uses clause to see if this would fix the issue but it did not.

Is there a way to find out which unit is using Quick Reports?

Comment: Are you building / compiling with packages? If so, could it be brought in by the packages list in the project options? IDE tends to add all installed packages to that list. When you open such a project in a newer Delphi, you may face the problem you are describing as included packages can change with each Delphi version.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Delphi Unit Dependency Scanner](http://www.easy-ip.net/delphi-unit-dependency-scanner.html), which can list all units used and their interdependencies. Finding unused units is also a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Icarus in the past to generate a uses report for cleaning up my own delphi code.  You can find it at http://www.peganza.com/products_icarus.htm.  I am not affiliated with the company, I just like their tools (Pascal Analyzer especially - great offline profiler).